# How can you keep the Rueful Axe and the Masque of Clavicus Vile?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am at the end of the quest given by the Daedric Prince Clavicus Vile, and I have done this quest in another profile so I know about the option at the end where you can either keep The Rueful Axe or get the Masque of Clavicus Vile.

My question is: Can you keep both the axe and the mask somehow? I have tried to figure out how but I have had no luck - anybody got an idea how I could keep them both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on the PC, you can pick one then add the other to your inventory via a console command:

Rueful axe:

> player.additem 1c4e6 1

Masque:

> player.additem d2846 1

If you are on the console, you can still obtain both:

[The wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/A_Daedra%27s_Best_Friend) shows a rather involved exploit you can do to keep both involving the slow time shout and a weapon rack which requires you to use the shout then travel to your weapon rack and placing the rueful axe on it while Clavicus is having a dialog with Barbas.

Comment: The second way can u do it for xbox because i use a xbox not a pc

Comment: @jasonvalderrama yep, and its been confirmed to still work as of the latest patch on the xbox

Comment: Cool thanks the last time i didn't know this site and just took the mask i was feeling nice lol im gald i found this site awhile back its useful even though im guessing most people look for the answers lol thanks again

Comment: oh and can u send me a link for the exploit

Comment: @jasonvalderrama the link is in the answer, if you click on the wiki link its there at the bottom.

Comment: o can't find the exploit on wiki can u send me a link to the exploit

Comment: @jasonvalderrama goto the link in my answer, scroll down to the bugs section, its right there at the bottom: "Its possible (through complicated) to obtain both....."

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. Unless exploiting a glitch (which I have never seen or heard of), you can only keep one or the other.

If you're on the PC, you can use the console to get back the item you gave up on in the quest using the command 'player.additem 0001C4E6 1' for the rueful axe or 'player.additem D246 1' for the mask.